# Can a company force you not to take annual leave during a notice period?

Tags: united-kingdom, notice-period, vacation

I have just resigned in my current company and I briefly mentioned I have unused annual leave left to take.

They have told me that it is company policy to pay leaving employees for unused annual leave, and thus their preferred option is that I do not take my remaining annual leave. Is that actually enforceable?

My employment contract doesn't specifically say that.

Comment: You mentioned their preferred option, but this does not sound like you have no choice. Even if they prefer that, they might not prevent you from taking all the leave you want. If you have the information, add it to your question - otherwise you could ask them directly whether, while you understand their preference, you can still take some of your days.

Comment: Some companies don't pay for unused days so you have not options but to use them.

Comment: @Paparazzi Notice the UK tag.

Comment: Specifiying the country is useful in this situation as this  depends on local law. (thisalmost belongs on the law site http://law.stackexchange.com/), in australia its generally no, but not sure about united-kingdom,

Comment: What does your employment contract/agreement say - there should be a section on termination/notice

Comment: @HorusKol, all it says is "On leaving the Company, it is at our sole discretion whether you are required to take any accrued annual leave entitlement during your notice period. Employees will be paid for any unused annual leave upon leaving the company."

Comment: so, yeah - they can pretty much dictate how much leave you can take during your notice - that said, when I was running out a 3 month notice period under the same conditions, I had a few weeks annual leave up my sleeve and I was able to take a week off - sometimes the company would rather you not come in for a day rather than pay the extra salary for accrued leave

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically leave must be approved, so theoretically they could prevent you from taking it by refusing to approve it.

Your answer indicates they would **prefer** you not take it, which is quite reasonable.

> Here's my notice, I need to take Friday off to deal with some personal stuff.

is a lot different than

> Here's my notice, my last day is in 2 weeks.  BTW, I'm taking 2 weeks of leave.

Any reasonable manager would approve the first and not approve the second. The latter is effectively giving no notice and would burn bridges.

Comment: Fair comment, it's 4 days, so 4 days out of 4 week notice period, it's probable that some managers would see that as far too long.

Comment: the only thing to do is ask - maybe ask for 4 day weeks?

Answer (score 3):

> ***their preferred option***

Sounds to me like they can't stop you, but they'd rather you actually prepare to hand over your projects and files rather than sit at home for the duration of your notice period.

It's your choice whether to force the issue or not, and its within the realm of possibility that they might get angry and throw you a curve-ball at some later time out of spite.

Comment: I think you're missing how British Understatement works.

Comment: The iron fist in the velvet glove :-) "We would ***prefer*** it if you would cooperate ... <alternative left unspoken>".