# Can I take paid-time off during my notice period and will I still receive my bonus during that time?

Tags: notice-period, bonus, leave

I live in the US. I have job offer at another company. Is it a good idea to give 2 weeks notice of quitting my job and request to use my remaining holiday at the same time? I plan to come back only on the day that everyone receive their annual bonus (or work for a few more days, depending on what is acceptable.)

Will the company refuse to let me use my remaining holiday and not let me receive bonus? Will I leave a bad impression?

My contract does not require me to give 2 weeks notice. Both the employer and the employee can choose to terminate the employment at any time.

Comment: You might want to check the employee handbook and/or other HR resources to see if they have an official policy on this.

Comment: The employee handbook says that I can't take any PTO time after a resignation has been submitted.

Comment: We don't have holidays, and all are PTO. The handbook says the employer may or may not grant PTO, based on business needs.

Comment: Should I request for PTO first and then submit the resignation notice immediately after the PTO request is granted?

Comment: "Will they let me do something that's expressly forbidden according to the employee handbook?" I don't understand why you're asking this question. No-one will tell you "yeah, the employee handbook is wrong, go for it", but of course there's always the possibility of an exception being made if you make a good case. Note the phrasing you used - you "can't **take** any PTO", not you "can't **request** any PTO".

Comment: If you're not required to give 2-weeks notice, why are you giving notice when that just complicates your life and why would the employee handbook imply that you're required to give notice or "punish" people for being nice and giving notice? Something here doesn't add up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a company force you not to take annual leave during a notice period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80168/can-a-company-force-you-not-to-take-annual-leave-during-a-notice-period)

Comment: See also [Is it unprofessional to ask for vacation in your notice period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76466/is-it-unprofessional-to-ask-for-vacation-in-your-notice-period)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a good idea to give 2 weeks notice of quitting my job and
>   request to use my remaining holiday at the same time?

It makes sense to give 2 weeks notice. That is standard US business practice.

You can request the use of your remaining holiday. That request may or may not be granted.

Some companies use the notice period to transition your work to others. Other companies would be happier not to see you in the office at all.

> I plan to come back only on the day that everyone receive their annual
>   bonus.

It's a reasonable plan. But some companies won't pay you an annual bonus after you have already given your notice, while others will. It depends on your contract, and perhaps local laws.

**If you want to ensure that you get your bonus, don't hand in your notice until you have the check in your hands.** In my experience, that's what folks usually do.

> Will I leave a bad impression?

Probably not. Do you care much?

Comment: My only fear is how will that affect my new job. I will start on my new job in the near future and the employer says that they will ask BIG to perform a background check on behalf of them. In the background check list, BIG says that they will call my current employer two weeks before I start my new job. If I leave a bad impression, would they let BIG know and thus affect my new employment? Although I leave due to personal emergency and have a legit reason, my current employer may not feel the same and may hold grudges against me.

Comment: Or I should say, family emergency.

Comment: I need to take care of some family issues.

Answer (score 0):

Giving your two weeks notice and requesting a vacation at the same time is a risky move. The two weeks notice (while not legally required) helps companies tie loose ends on the current projects you're working on while seeking a replacement. If the company knows you're going to be leaving they may not want to approve your vacation time.

Abandoning your last two weeks to go on vacation would leave a bad impression if the company was depending on you to wrap things up. What if they decide to terminate you before your 2 weeks because you're not going to be working anyway?

If you really want to have your vacation, bonus, and leave on a good note, I'd recommend taking your vacation ASAP, then giving your 2 notice weeks notice after you come back and receive your bonus. That's a lot more time consuming and may not be worth the trouble so it's really up to you.

Comment: thanks guys. I am thinking about coming in and taking off in between so i can still take my PTO while help finish the work on hand. Would it be reasonable if I negotiate my PTO while expressing my need to resign at the same time? I am going to take PTO while there isn't much to do, and then come back and work when they need me. It is difficult and goes against my schedule so there are certainly some days that I really need to take off, but I also understand that my coworkers need me.

Comment: I think that's perfectly reasonable, and I'm sure your boss will appreciate your integrity and flexibility while completing your work.

Comment: I would recommend giving notice after the bonus is in your bank account, or you risk losing your bonus. I can't say whether you would be legally entitled to the bonus after giving notice, but it's much harder to get the money back from you than to just not send it.

Comment: I have never worked for a company in over 40 years of work that would allow an employee to take even a planner vacation during the notice period.